# Как нажать элемент меню в Codesys2.3 при помощи pywinauto?

Tags: pywinauto

Есть приложение codesys 2.3. У него есть меню "Онлайн -> Подключение"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\3S Software\CoDeSys V2.3\Codesys.exe")
app[u'CoDeSys'][u'Приложение'].print_control_identifiers()
```

Control Identifiers:

```
Menu - 'Приложение'    (L3, T39, R1919, B63)
['ПриложениеMenu', 'Menu', 'Приложение']
child_window(title="Приложение", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Файл'    (L3, T39, R57, B63)
   | ['ФайлMenuItem', 'MenuItem', 'Файл', 'MenuItem0', 'MenuItem1']
   | child_window(title="Файл", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Правка'    (L56, T39, R124, B63)
   | ['ПравкаMenuItem', 'MenuItem2', 'Правка']
   | child_window(title="Правка", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Проект'    (L124, T39, R192, B63)
   | ['Проект', 'MenuItem3', 'ПроектMenuItem']
   | child_window(title="Проект", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Вставить'    (L191, T39, R269, B63)
   | ['Вставить', 'MenuItem4', 'ВставитьMenuItem']
   | child_window(title="Вставить", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Дополнения'    (L269, T39, R373, B63)
   | ['MenuItem5', 'Дополнения', 'ДополненияMenuItem']
   | child_window(title="Дополнения", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Онлайн'    (L373, T39, R444, B63)
   | ['MenuItem6', 'Онлайн', 'ОнлайнMenuItem']
   | child_window(title="Онлайн", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Окно'    (L444, T39, R498, B63)
   | ['ОкноMenuItem', 'MenuItem7', 'Окно']
   | child_window(title="Окно", control_type="MenuItem")
   |
   | MenuItem - 'Справка'    (L498, T39, R573, B63)
   | ['Справка', 'MenuItem8', 'СправкаMenuItem']
   | child_window(title="Справка", control_type="MenuItem")
```

Для

```
MenuItem - 'Онлайн'    (L373, T39, R444, B63)
   | ['MenuItem6', 'Онлайн', 'ОнлайнMenuItem']
   | child_window(title="Онлайн", control_type="MenuItem")
```

недоступны методы menu(), menu_select() и print_control_identifiers().

```
print(app[u'CoDeSys'][u'Приложение'][u'Онлайн'])
print(app[u'CoDeSys'][u'Приложение'][u'Онлайн'][u'Подключение'])
```

Возвращают ошибки:

```
AttributeError: The control does not have a __getitem__ method for item access (i.e. ctrl[key]) so maybe you have requested this in error?
```

Решить задачу получилось при помощи send_keys('%{F8}') но хотелось бы обратиться к разделу меню средствами библиотеки, а не через горячие клавиши или эмуляцию нажатия кнопок. Это возможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По непонятной для меня причине при использовании UIA бекенда в MFC-приложении недоступны элементы меню.

Код ниже использует win32 бекенд:

```
app = Application(backend="win32").start(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\3S Software\CoDeSys V2.3\Codesys.exe")
wnd = app[u'CoDeSys']
wnd.wait('ready')
wnd.menu().get_menu_path(u'Онлайн->Подключение')[-1].select()
```